# Gradle multi project distribution

Tags: package, gradle, multi-project

I'm trying to make a dist of a multi project build. The root project looks something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'
version 1.0
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = 'someName'
        contents {
            from 'nodes' 
        into 'nodes'
        }
    }
}
```

It just copies a folder with some files to the dist.

I now want each subproject to inject its stuff into the dist. I want to add each subprojects jar, any dependecies, and possibly some other files etc...

I have no idea how to inject from the subproject to the root. Should I even do something like that? What i mean is something like this:

```
subprojects {
   apply java...
   ...

   // pseudocode
   jack into the root project dist plugin
   put my produced jars and dependencies in a folder with my name
   ...
}
```

Does anyone have any examples, or just point me in the right direction?

thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for the same thing. With some peeking at the API docs and Gradle' own build files, I came to the following:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into('bin') {
                from { project(':subproject1').startScripts.outputs.files }
                from { project(':subproject2').startScripts.outputs.files }
                fileMode = 0755
            }
            into('lib') {
                def libs = []
                libs << project(':subproject1').configurations.runtime - project(':runner').configurations.runtime
                libs << project(':subproject2').configurations.runtime
                from libs
                from project(':subproject1').jar
                from project(':subproject2').jar
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [contents {}](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/distribution/Distribution.html#contents%28org.gradle.api.Action%29) closure is a [CopySpec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html), knowing that makes using the distribution plugin way simpler :)

Check out Gradle' own subprojects/distributions/distributions.gradle file for some great examples of using the CopySpec.

This works.

- The substraction is to remove duplicated jars.
- The ".jar" lines are to add the jar of that project as the configurations.runtime only seem to contain the dependenceis.

Sadly, currently I've no clue on how to scale this to more than two projects in a clean way. Atleast we're one step closer :)

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution that has been working well for me. The key is that you **add a separate subproject for creating the dist**. This subproject is **sibling** to the other subprojects. That is, do not try to script the distribution in your top-level `build.gradle` file.

Let's call the new subproject `dist`.  The first thing to do is to add it to your top-level `settings.gradle` file in your multi-project root:

```
include "subproject1", "subproject2", "subproject3", ....... , "dist"
```

Your `dist` project must at minimum include:

- `build.gradle` - to be detailed below
- `src/main/dist/at_least_one_dummy_file.txt` - the distribution plugin always requires a `src/main/$distribution.name` directory. Having a non-empty one with a  `distribution.name` of `main` tricks the plugin into following all the transitive dependencies of all the `main` sourcesets of all the sibling projects.

Next, the `build.gradle` file for the `dist` project:

```
/* Hook in all sibling project jars and their transitive dependencies */
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile project(':subproject1')
    compile project(':subproject2')
    compile project(':subproject3')
    . . . 
}

/* Distribution */
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = "your-top-level-project-name"
        contents {
            exclude "dist-${version}.jar"
            . . . 
        }
    }
}
```

Then run `gradle distZip`.  The `ZIP` file in `dist/build/distributions` will have a `lib` subdirectory with every single `JAR` you want: the sibling project `JAR`s and their transitive dependencies.

Because of the trickery we used, the distribution plugin will make an empty `JAR` called `dist-${version}.jar`.  For cosmetic reasons, I remove it with the `exclude` call above, but it is harmless.  You could also use a second `exclude` call to remove the `at_least_one_dummy_file.txt` if there really is no content under `src/main/dist` that you want to include.  If you do not want add any artifacts and/or remove the ones mentioned here, then you don't even need a `contents` section at all.

I also have found ways of selectively including different artifacts based on whether this is a "dev" or "prod" distribution, a la Maven profiles. If you want me to add that, please post in comments and I will.

Answer (score 3):

I actually made it work by combining the approaches from both, pvdissel and sparc_spread.

In my root project I created a directory `src/main/dist` where I put exactly one file called `.gitkeep`.

The `build.gradle` file of my root project looks as follows:

```java
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

allprojects {
    ....
}

dependencies {
    // let root project depend on all subprojects that have the
    // application plugin enabled
    project.subprojects.each { p ->
        p.plugins.withType(ApplicationPlugin) {
            compile p
        }
    }
}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            // exclude unnecessary files from archive
            exclude ".gitkeep"
            exclude "cs3d-toolbox-${version}.jar"

            // add start scripts of all plugins that have the
            // application plugin enabled to the archive
            project.subprojects.each { p ->
                p.plugins.withType(ApplicationPlugin) {
                    into('bin') {
                        from { p.startScripts.outputs.files }
                        fileMode = 0755
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works quite well for me. Tested with Gradle 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is the setup I'm using in a project with multiple libraries to create a "release" archive:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
  main {
    baseName = libVersion
    contents {
      project.subprojects.each { sub ->
        into('lib') {
          from sub.jar
        }
        into('src') {
          from sub.sourcesJar
        }
        into('doc') {
          from sub.javadocJar
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using `distZip` task creates an archive with all libraries with their files separated into three folders (`lib` contains the actual jars, `src` contains jars with sources and `doc` contains - you guessed it - Javadoc jars).

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that.

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into('lib') {
                from subprojects*.jar
                from subprojects*.configurations.runtimeClasspath
            }
            into('doc') {
                from subprojects*.javadocJar
            }
        }
    }
}
```